# Android device orientation change

Tags: android, orientation

I am looking for any sugestion how to change Fragment from portrait orientation to landscape.

My application is always in portrait mode, I need change only one fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify orientation for the activity holding the fragment in manifest

android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in the fragments you want to change and it should do the trick

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: that should be `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` as per question.